# Arrays break string types in Julia

Tags: arrays, string, types, julia

Is the following by design?

`ASCIIString <: String` returns `true`, but  `Array{ASCIIString,1} <: Array{String,1}` returns `false`.

Perhaps this is a bug, and I should make a pull request on github. (I'm running v0.4.0-dev+6210)

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. `Int <: Number` returns true and `Array{Int,1} <: Array{Number,1}` returns false. please read the [document](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#parametric-composite-types) carefully.

Comment: @GnimucKey, thanks! I see the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just convert my comment into an answer:

the answer to your question is YES. As julia's [document](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#man-parametric-types) says:

> in the parlance of type theory, Julia’s type parameters are *invariant*, rather than being covariant (or even contravariant).

in the misleading case below, one may find that

```
julia> Int64 <: Int
true

julia> Array{Int64,1} <: Array{Int,1}
true
```

this is because `Int` and `Int64` are the same type.

```
julia> xdump(Int)
Int64::DataType  <: Signed

julia> xdump(Int64)
Int64::DataType  <: Signed

julia> xdump(Array{Int,1})
Array{Int64,1}::DataType  <: DenseArray{Int64,1}

julia> xdump(Array{Int64,1})
Array{Int64,1}::DataType  <: DenseArray{Int64,1}
```

we can use `typejoin` to checkout the relationship between type `A` and type `B` and their corresponding "arrays".

```
julia> typejoin(Int64,Int)
Int64

julia> typejoin(Array{Int64,1},Array{Int,1})
Array{Int64,1}
```

but

```
julia> typejoin(ASCIIString,String)
String

julia> typejoin(Array{String,1},Array{ASCIIString,1})
Array{T,N} (constructor with 9 methods)
```