# Sparse matrices and type constraints in Julia

Tags: methods, types, julia

I am confused about how parametric methods work in Julia. I also hope that parametric is the right word to use here. I've read the docs on methods but it is still not clear why the following error occurs. If I define a function as below

```
function Bazinga{T<:Real}(mat ::Union{Array{T,2},SparseMatrixCSC})
    mat^4
end
```

and run

```
Penny = sparse(randn(10,10))
Bazinga(Penny)
```

I get

```
ERROR: MethodError: `Bazinga` has no method matching Bazinga(::SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64})
Closest candidates are:
  Bazinga{T<:Real}(::Union{Array{T<:Real,2},SparseMatrixCSC{Tv,Ti<:Integer}})
```

But `Int64<:Int` is true so what is the problem here? 
If I redefine the function as

```
function Bazinga(mat ::Union{Array{Real,2},SparseMatrixCSC})
    mat^4
end
```

no error is produced and the function works. Also there are now two methods of the function

```
Bazinga(mat::Union{Array{Real,2},SparseMatrixCSC{Tv,Ti<:Integer}}) at none:2
Bazinga{T<:Real}(mat::Union{Array{T<:Real,2},SparseMatrixCSC{Tv,Ti<:Integer}}) at none:2
```

in which both `SparseMatrixCSC{Tv,Ti<:Integer}` is in, but only in the first case it causes an error. 
Any input is wellcome!

Edit1: And why is `Array{Float64,1} <:Array{Real,1}` false? 
Edit2: The question in the Edit1 is solved by [Arrays break string types in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691792/arrays-break-string-types-in-julia) . But I don't think it explains what happens with the method. Or at least I don't see it.

Comment: `Bazinga{T<:Real}(mat::Union{Array{T,2},SparseMatrixCSC{T}) = mat^4` works. Seems Julia likes all elements of union have the same parameter "template". This is possibly a known issue and someone familiar with it will answer.

Comment: Most probably, above issue is because the Union chooses the SparseMatrixCSC branch and then because T is unused it cannot fill the parameter T and decide the method matched the call.

Comment: @Dan Getz That sounds like it could be the reason. I used your suggestion above to fix my code, so thanks a lot for that! I'd like to give both, you and `@Gnimuc K.`,credits but I doubt there is a way to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite know the reason under the hood, but using a `TypeVar` may be a workaround for your use case:

```
T = TypeVar(:T, Union{}, Real, false)

function Bazinga(mat::Union{Array{T,2},SparseMatrixCSC})
    mat^4
end

julia> Bazinga(sparse(randn(2,2)))
2x2 sparse matrix with 4 Float64 entries:
    [1, 1]  =  0.840151
    [2, 1]  =  -0.503551
    [1, 2]  =  -0.437787
    [2, 2]  =  1.28652

julia> Bazinga(randn(2,2))
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.203916   -0.261589 
 0.0107211  -0.0137373
```

### UPDATE:

After some investigation, I find the "canonical" way to solve this problem is to define a `typealias`:

```
typealias RealMatrix{T<:Real} Array{T, 2}

function Bazinga(mat::Union{RealMatrix, SparseMatrixCSC})
    mat^4
end
```

I guess the reason is Julia can't complete method matching tasks without knowing what on earth all of the parametric types are. Here is another example:

```
Foo{R<:Real,C<:Complex}(x::Union{Array{R}, SparseMatrixCSC{C}}) = x
```

Neither `Foo(sparse([1+im 2; 3 4]))` nor `Foo(rand(2,2))` will work. So the correct way to write a parametric-union method is to constrain those different parameters via `typealias`:

```
julia> typealias Bar{T<:Real} Array{T,2}
Array{T<:Real,2}

julia> typealias Baz{T<:Complex} SparseMatrixCSC{T}
SparseMatrixCSC{T<:Complex{T<:Real},Ti<:Integer}

julia> Foo(x::Union{Bar, Baz}) = x
Foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> Foo(rand(2,2))
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.000739447  0.713386
 0.32024      0.705593

julia> Foo(sparse([1+im; 2im]))
2x1 sparse matrix with 2 Complex{Int64} entries:
    [1, 1]  =  1+1im
    [2, 1]  =  0+2im
```

If argument types of the union have the same type parameter `T`, we can also use `typealias` as follows:

```
julia> typealias MyUnion{T,N<:Integer} Union{Array{T,2}, SparseMatrixCSC{T,N}}
Union{Array{T,2},SparseMatrixCSC{T,N<:Integer}}

julia> Foo{T<:Real}(x::MyUnion{T}) = x
Foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> Foo(rand(2,2))
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0172915  0.587518  
 0.234148   0.00543953

julia> Foo(rand(2))
ERROR: MethodError: `Foo` has no method matching Foo(::Array{Float64,1})

julia> Foo(sparse(rand(2)))
2x1 sparse matrix with 2 Float64 entries:
    [1, 1]  =  0.900029
    [2, 1]  =  0.0634815

julia> Foo(sparse(rand(2,2)))
2x2 sparse matrix with 4 Float64 entries:
    [1, 1]  =  0.592632
    [2, 1]  =  0.066563
    [1, 2]  =  0.805307
    [2, 2]  =  0.923422

julia> Foo(rand(2,2))
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.167078  0.673194
 0.681418  0.316017
```

### UPDATE 2:

In Julia-v0.6+, defining the typealias is not necessary:

```
function Bazinga(mat::Union{Array{<:Real,2},SparseMatrixCSC})
    mat^4
end
```

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366901/julia-fails-to-multiple-dispatch) for further details.

Comment: @olga.bio actually, `typealias` is the recommended way, see update above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed reply! That clarifies the issue