# Julia fails to multiple dispatch

Tags: julia

v06
I want to write a signature that expect 2 to 3 arguments. The first one is either an Integer or Vector of Integer. The second one is either a Vector of Integer or Matrix of Integer. The third one is either a Vector of Integer or not specified.

I first tried it like this

```
function foo(
a::Union{Integer, Vector{Integer}},
b::Union{Vector{Integer}, Matrix{Integer}},
c::Union{Void, Vector{Integer}} = nothing)
```

When I call this like this `foo(3, [0o7, 0o5])` I get an error telling me that it is unable to match.

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching foo(::Int64, ::Array{UInt8,1})
Closest candidates are:
  foo(::Union{Array{Integer,1}, Integer}, !Matched::Union{Array{Integer,1}, Array{Integer,2}}) at ...
  foo(::Union{Array{Integer,1}, Integer}, !Matched::Union{Array{Integer,1}, Array{Integer,2}}, !Matched::Union{Array{Integer,1}, Void}) at ...
```

Now I understand why julia is unable to match this `Array{UInt8} <: Array{Integer} == false`, but this just seems to be not smart of julia.

Then I tried this

```
foo(a::Union{Z1, Vector{Z1}},
    b::Union{Vector{Z2}, Matrix{Z2}},
    c::Union{Void, Vector{Z3}} = nothing
    ) where {Z1 <: Integer, Z2 <: Integer, Z3 <: Integer}
```

Now julia does not even tell me what does not match!

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching foo(::Int64, ::Array{UInt8,1}, ::Void)
Closest candidates are:
  foo(::Union{Array{Z1<:Integer,1}, Z1<:Integer}, ::Union{Array{Z2<:Integer,1}, Array{Z2<:Integer,2}}, ::Union{Array{Z3<:Integer,1}, Void}) where {Z1<:Integer, Z2<:Integer, Z3<:Integer} at ...
  foo(::Union{Array{Z1<:Integer,1}, Z1<:Integer}, ::Union{Array{Z2<:Integer,1}, Array{Z2<:Integer,2}}) where {Z1<:Integer, Z2<:Integer} at ...
```

Comment: When you have very complicated type signatures like this, especially with lots of unions, it may be a sign that you should split it into several separate method definitions. In particular, you probably want at least to avoid the `foo(a, b, c=nothing)`, in favour of `foo(a, b, c)` and `foo(a, b)`. Also, consider whether there is a connection between the types, for example, is `a` a `Vector` only when `b` is a `Matrix`?

Comment: @DNF I understand your concern. The problem is that if I do that that the user gets useless julia error messages instead of the useful ones that I write. E.g. "No method exists where you have a matrix for b and c is Void", i rather have it like this "If you specify b as a matrix you have to specify c as a vector with these dimensions". Infact this signature is the bullshit-check-signature that calls the real method after having checked everything and casted everything to the right type.

Comment: You're setting yourself up to do a whole lot of explicit input checking, which goes against the idea of multiple dispatch. You're causing yourself a lot of pain just to avoid letting people be exposed to ordinary Julia error messages. Also, I would be surprised to be told that `c` is `Void`, if I didn't supply any `c` at all! Suggestion: Split your function into separate methods with correct signatures. Then make a fallback method (or several) that catches the rest: `f(a, b, c) = ...` without types, and let that one figure out what's wrong with the inputs and issue errors.

Comment: Not certain exactly what you want, but something like: `foo(a::Integer, b::Vector{<:Integer}) = ... end`
`foo(a::Vector{<:Integer}, b::Matrix{<:Integer}, c::Vector{<:Integer}) = ... end`
`foo(a::Integer, b...) = error("If a is an Integer, b must be a Vector of Integers.") end`
`foo(a::Vector{<:Integer}, b...) = error("If a is an Vector of Integers, b must be a Matrix of Integers and c must be a Vector of Integers...") end`   (ends added for readability, it's not actually correct to use them.) I think this will actually make it easier to write good error messages.

Comment: I do not see benefit in doing it like that for my current problem. I do not believe that this makes my code more readable.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure it does (when you add newlines. In fact I'm 99% sure it does.) But to each according to taste.

Comment: Sorry to go on about this, but you are basically embracing the difficult and annoying parts of multiple dispatch (getting complex function signatures correct) while rejecting the benefits (avoiding explicit input type checking, separation of logically different methods, etc..) IMHO this is the single greatest strength of Julia, so it's just puzzling to me that you want to throw that (as well as possibly performance) overboard by writing non-idiomatic code.

Comment: Because it is more readable this way. If there is a way to pm people here I would send you the relevant part of the code and show you how it looks if I would do it like you suggest. In the end the difficult way would be easier to read.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155117/discussion-between-dnf-and-nozdrum).

Comment: x-ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079213/sparse-matrices-and-type-constraints-in-julia/39080851#39080851

Comment: Just to be clear, these signatures do not help performance at all. They are just for dispatching and throwing errors. This is a very convoluted way of doing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `Array{UInt8} <: Array{Integer} == false`.  This is called "parametric invariance."  Lots of other questions have discussed this topic.

The other problem you're running into, though, is that when you use a static function parameter — that is, `f(…) where T` — the `T` *must* match something since it's available for use in the body of the function.  This causes trouble in `Union`s where `T` isn't available in every option.  I believe there's an open issue about changing this behavior to allow matching `Union` elements that don't contain `T`, which would turn that binding into an undefined variable if you tried to access it.

The workaround right now is to use type vars that *aren't* static parameters of the function.  E.g.,

```
   foo(a::Union{Integer, Vector{<:Integer}},
       b::Union{Vector{<:Integer}, Matrix{<:Integer}},
       c::Union{Void, Vector{<:Integer}} = nothing) = 1
```

Comment: IIRC, in old days when triangular dispatch was not supported, we have to define a `typealias` to work around this, e.g. `typealias IntVector{T<:Integer} Vector{T}`, `foo(x::Union{Integer, IntVector}) = x`. Glad to see this is no longer needed anymore!